# Add Symbol dynamically in JS with Animate CC

Tags: javascript, jquery-animate, adobe

I'm struggling inserting a occurencde of a symbol in an Animate CC stage.
it should work like:

```
var fl_MyInstance_4 = new lib.MySymbol();
this.addChild(fl_MyInstance_4);
```

but it always return that lib.MySymbol is not a constructor.
I also read that "Add "LibrarySymbol" as the linkage property of the symbol" but when I access the properties of my Symbol, all linkage option a greyed, and I can't do anything in the advanced panel.

So how can you add an occurence of a symbol dynamically through JS?

Answer (score 0):

My bad...I actually was chasing the Linkage Option in the wrong place. 
It's not in properties as you can do for AS3, but simply by double clikcing in the Linkage column in the Library panel...